# Can't access my VPS through SSH

Tags: 20.04, ssh, sh, etc

I just misconfigured my `/etc/passwd` had used this command on root login

```
root@ubuntu:~# sh -c 'echo "nope no entry mates" > /etc/passwd'
```

Now whenever I try to access my VPS though any user, or root account, I get

```
ssh root@myVpsIp
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset
```

SSH Debug

```
C:\Users\tommy>ssh root@myVpsIp -v    
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to myVpsIp [myVpsIp] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\tommy/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\tommy/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\tommy/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\tommy/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\tommy/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\tommy/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\tommy/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\tommy/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\tommy/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\tommy/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

There is still a logged in root ssh window in which I tried to find the problem solution and got to the issue

```
root@ubuntu:~# cut -d : -f 1 /etc/passwd
nope no entry mates
```

Anybody know how to restore my `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: had user pwck -qr and it shows my user accounts are there had followd this guide  [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-restrict-log-in-capabilities-of-users-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if you have backup of /etc/passwd located in /var/backups/passwd.bak and if you have run `cp /var/backups/passwd.bak /etc/passwd` and then run `chmod 644 /etc/passwd`

If you don't have /var/backups/passwd.bak, you can use /etc/passwd-

It seems you have deleted your entire /etc/passwd file with the first command that you've run.

Comment: voila you're right. had just moved from widows 10 to linux trying to learn operating linux using vps